# How to slice a torch tensor without using python indexing

Tags: pytorch

My pytorch code below keeps getting jit tracer warning (in pytorch 1.1.0 environment) complaining that "Pytorch 1.0 Tracer Warning: Converting a tensor to a Python index might ..."

Is there a way to implement the code line marked (A) below without using python indexing?

```
N,C,H,W = input.size()
Cout=4*C
Hout=H//2
Wout=W//2
downsampled=torch.zeros([N,Cout,Hout,Wout], dtype= torch.FloatTensor)
downsampled[:,1:Cout:4,:,:]=input[:,:,0::2,1::2] ---- (A)
```

Comment: Works in 1.2 at least.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that jit tracer no longer complains the python indexing in Pytorch 1.2 (as Umang Gupta commented).

BTW, I came up with an implementation with no slicing (but still using indexing) as follow:

```
import torch

input=torch.arange(100)
input=input.view(10,10)
input=input[None, None, ...].expand(2,3,10,10) #torch.Size([2,3,10,10])

N,C,H,W=input.size()
Cout=4*C
Hout=H//2
Wout=W//2

downsampled=torch.zeros([N,Cout,Hout,Wout],dtype=torch.int8) #torch.Size([2,12,5,5])

dim2_idx=torch.tensor([k for k in range(0,H,2)])
dim3_idx=torch.tensor([k for k in range(1,W,2)])
sliced_input=input.index_select(2,dim2_idx).index_select(3,dim3_idx) #torch.Size([2,3,5,5])

#downsampled.index_select(1,torch.tensor([k for k in range(1,Cout,4)]))=temp <---Error: Can't assign to function call

for idx in range(1,Cout,4):
    downsampled[:,idx,:,:]=sliced_input[:,idx//4,:,:]
```